# How save information to file in python? (simple programming)

Tags: python, file, text, save

In the program below, I have created a class called "Tv" and from this class I have instantiated two objects, which are called "vardagsrums_tv" and "koks_tv". In the main function of the program, the user can change different settings in both of the objects, *e.g.*, volume and channel, through certain class methods I have created. So far, so good.

The heart of the matter, though, is that when the user has changed these different settings (volume, channel), I want to save them to a text file, so that when the user shuts down the program and reopens it, all the settings will be as the user left them.

This is my program:

```
def main():
vardagsrums_tv = Tv(read_file(2), read_file(1))
koks_tv = Tv(read_file(5), read_file(4))
choice = None
print("***Välkommen till TV-simulatorn***")
while choice != "3":
    print("""
          1. Vardagsrums TV
          2. Köks TV
          3. Avsluta
          """)
    choice = input("Välj ett alternativ: ")
    print("")




    while choice == "1":
        print(vardagsrums_tv)
        print("""
              1. Byt kanal
              2. Sänk ljudvolymen
              3. Höj ljudvolymen
              4. Återvänd till huvudmenyn
              """)
        choice_one = input("Välj ett alternativ: ")
        if choice_one == "1":
            vardagsrums_tv.byt_kanal()
        elif choice_one == "2":
            vardagsrums_tv.sank_volym()
        elif choice_one == "3":
            vardagsrums_tv.hoj_volym()
        elif choice_one == "4":
            choice = None
            break
        else:
            print("Var god välj ett av de fyra alternativen.")




    while choice == "2":
        print(koks_tv)
        print("""
              1. Byt kanal
              2. Sänk ljudvolymen
              3. Höj ljudvolymen
              4. Återvänd till huvudmenyn
              """)
        choice_two = input("Välj ett alternativ: ")
        if choice_two == "1":
            koks_tv.byt_kanal()
        elif choice_two == "2":
            koks_tv.sank_volym()
        elif choice_two == "3":
            koks_tv.hoj_volym()
        elif choice_two == "4":
            choice = None
            break
        else:
            print("Var god välj ett av de fyra alternativen.")




    if choice not in ("1", "2", "3", None):
        print("Du har angivit ett felaktigt alternativ. Försök igen!")
lista_1 = []
lista_1.append(vardagsrums_tv)
print(lista_1)
lista_2 =[]
lista_2.append(koks_tv)
write_file(lista_1, lista_2)
```

In the end of my main() function, you'll notice that I am experimenting on how to save the current settings to my text-file. I create a list and try to somehow get the information out of my objects "vardagsrums_tv" and "koks_tv". I thought, if you can print an object and get the settings, then you might also be able to append it to a list. Obviously it didn't work as planned, since I got an error.

I hope you understand what I am trying to do: I want to save information from inside an object (vardagsrums_tv, koks_tv) to a text file, but I seem not to be able to reace the information I want.

Here is the rest of program:

```
def read_file(val):
val = val
text_file = open("C:\\Users\\Viktor\\Desktop\\laboration_5.txt", "r")
textrader = text_file.readlines()
lista = []
for i in range(len(textrader)):
    text_line = textrader[i]
    element = text_line.split(",")
    lista += element[0], element[1], element[2]
text_file.close()
return lista[val]

def write_file(tv_1, tv_2):
rad_1 = tv_1
rad_2 = tv_2
for i in range(len(vardagsrums_tv)):
    rad_1 += vardagsrums_tv[i], ","
for i in range(len(koks_tv)):
    rad_2 += koks_tv[i], ","
text_file = open("C:\\Users\\Viktor\\Desktop\\laboration_5.txt", "w")
text_file.append(rad_1)
text_file.append(rad_2)
text_file.close

class Tv(object):
"""En vardagsrums TV"""
def __init__(self, kanal, volym):
    self.kanal = int(kanal)
    self.volym = int(volym)




def __str__(self):
    rep = "Vardagsrums TV\n"
    rep += "Kanal: " + str(self.kanal) + "\n"
    rep += "Volym: " + str(self.volym) + "\n"
    return rep




def byt_kanal(self):
    kanal = int(input("Ange din önskade kanal: "))
    while kanal < 1 or kanal > 100:
        print("Du har angivet en felaktig kanal. Vänlig ange en kanal mellan 1 och 100!")
        kanal = int(input("Ange din önskade kanal: "))
    self.kanal = kanal




def hoj_volym(self, hoj = 1):
    self.volym += hoj
    if self.volym > 10:
        print("Du kan inte höja volymen ytterligare.")
        self.volym = 10




def sank_volym(self, sank = 1):
    self.volym -= sank
    if self.volym < 0:
        print("Du kan inte sänka volymen ytterligare.")
        self.volym = 0


def main():
vardagsrums_tv = Tv(read_file(2), read_file(1))
koks_tv = Tv(read_file(5), read_file(4))
choice = None
print("***Välkommen till TV-simulatorn***")
while choice != "3":
    print("""
          1. Vardagsrums TV
          2. Köks TV
          3. Avsluta
          """)
    choice = input("Välj ett alternativ: ")
    print("")




    while choice == "1":
        print(vardagsrums_tv)
        print("""
              1. Byt kanal
              2. Sänk ljudvolymen
              3. Höj ljudvolymen
              4. Återvänd till huvudmenyn
              """)
        choice_one = input("Välj ett alternativ: ")
        if choice_one == "1":
            vardagsrums_tv.byt_kanal()
        elif choice_one == "2":
            vardagsrums_tv.sank_volym()
        elif choice_one == "3":
            vardagsrums_tv.hoj_volym()
        elif choice_one == "4":
            choice = None
            break
        else:
            print("Var god välj ett av de fyra alternativen.")




    while choice == "2":
        print(koks_tv)
        print("""
              1. Byt kanal
              2. Sänk ljudvolymen
              3. Höj ljudvolymen
              4. Återvänd till huvudmenyn
              """)
        choice_two = input("Välj ett alternativ: ")
        if choice_two == "1":
            koks_tv.byt_kanal()
        elif choice_two == "2":
            koks_tv.sank_volym()
        elif choice_two == "3":
            koks_tv.hoj_volym()
        elif choice_two == "4":
            choice = None
            break
        else:
            print("Var god välj ett av de fyra alternativen.")




    if choice not in ("1", "2", "3", None):
        print("Du har angivit ett felaktigt alternativ. Försök igen!")
lista_1 = []
lista_1.append(vardagsrums_tv)
print(lista_1)
lista_2 =[]
lista_2.append(koks_tv)
write_file(lista_1, lista_2)

main()
input("Vänligen tryck enter för att avsluta.")
```

Comment: Have you considered [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)? Also read about it on [PMOTW](https://pymotw.com/2/pickle/). As for managing the objects, have a look at [shelve](https://pymotw.com/2/shelve/index.html#module-shelve)

Answer (score 1):

You should open your `laboration_5.txt` file with `"a"` (append) instead of `"w"` (write) or it will overwrite the file. Then use `text_file.write(data)` to then append data to this file. Make sure you close you file afterwards with `text_file.close()`.

```
text_file = open("C:\\Users\\Viktor\\Desktop\\laboration_5.txt", "a")
text_file.write(rad_1)
text_file.write(rad_2)
text_file.close()
```

Comment: `with` statements! Then you don't have to "make sure" of anything; Python handles it. `with open("C:\\Users\\Viktor\\Desktop\\laboration_5.txt", "a") as text_file:`, then put both `write`s in an indented block, and you don't need the `close` at all.

Comment: Agreed, but this was least impact on the authors original code. That seemed to be the situationally correct move.